# php div refreshed by javascript looses php session variables after 1st reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

**main.php :**

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "<div id='buttons'>";
include "buttons.php";
echo "</div>";
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function refreshButtons(){
    $('#buttons').load(document.URL +  ' #buttons');
}
```

**buttons.php :**

```
session_start();
$a=checkbuttons($_SESSION['userid']);
if ($a=="false") {
echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg'>Return to Main</button>";
}
else {
echo "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-lg'>Proceed</button>";
}
```

I have a main page that has a div that gets refresh every 10 seconds. It loads **buttons.php** that checks MySQL database returning either true or false based on users session id.

The page loads fine the 1st time, all variables are ok.

The problem I have is `$_SESSION['userid']` is empty after the 1st time JavaScript refreshes the div. And of-course after that the results from the query are always false. Session id stays the same, that I have already checked. I'm at a loss what to check next here. 
**buttons.php** starts it's own session every time it loads but still the variable is empty.

Comment: You have a syntax error in main.php and you haven't posted your `checkbuttons()` function.

Comment: as @Mike mentioned you need to include the checkbuttons() function.

Comment: it is hard to tell with the informations we have, but the first time, the code of buttons.php is directly included in main.php (probably causing session_start to be called twice), and the second time by Ajax call. Is the session stored in cookies? is it correctly maintained through the Ajax call? i could add, is not document.URL 'main.php'? where is this JS?

Answer (score 0):

checkbuttons() function queries mysql database returning true or false based on $_SESSION['userid'].

I managed to solve this by changing

```
        function refreshButtons(){
        $('#buttons').load(document.URL +  ' #buttons');
    }
```

to

```
    function refreshButtons(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "buttons.php",
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
             $("#buttons").html(data);
          } 
        });
}
```

edit:
What I think was happening was load(document.URL +  ' #buttons') was reloading the whole page without passing the session variable,
by loading the buttons.php via ajax reloads only that particular div thus passing the session variable.

ps. apologies for the bad formatting in my original post, it was quite late and I was quite frustrated at the time.